# Для чего нужен этот параметр?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Подскажет что означает, или для чего нужна запись:

`<script src="js/name.js?<?php echo time();?>"></script>`

Или

```
$.get('tiles.json?'+Math.random(),function(data){});
```

Зачем к именам файлов добавляются эти числа? Внутри файлов нет ничего связанного с ними.

Comment: чтобы исключить кэширование запроса браузером

Comment: Grundy прав, поскольку имя скрипта постоянно меняется, то браузер при следующем посещении страницы не обнаружит в кэше данного скрипта (он изменился) и загрузит его вновь. Это гарантирует, что пользователь получит последнюю версию скрипта, но замедляет повторную загрузку данной страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Эта «соль» используется для борьбы с кешированием в браузере.

Браузер кеширует вообще всё, до чего может добраться. Притом делает это чуть ли не случайно. Притом кеширует даже то, что ему указывается не кешировать (например, http-заголовком).

Браузер узнаёт, что файл не надо второй раз загружать, когда проверяет «а не загружал ли я уже этот url когда-то?». Чтобы он всегда получал уникальный url придумали такой хак: добавлять любую соль в get-параметр.

Для человека это примерно одни и те же запросы, а для браузера абсолютно разные

```
/index.php
/index.php?rand=12039
```

Answer (score 0):

решил ответом написать для пользователя @higimo

если в ответе установлен заголовок

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-cache
```

то ничего и не где не будет кэшироваться. Хак есть но не такой грубый смысла нет каждый раз обновлять кэшь обычно ставят какой то cache-key для этого который не меняеться пока нет необходимости отдать новую страницу. Да и так как браузер запрашивает по отдельности статику то грамотнее просто отдать last-modified

```
Last-modified: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 14:14:55 GMT
```

или expires

```
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
```

разница лишь в том что первый заголовок показывает когда в последний раз был изменён фаил, а второй когда стоит обновить кэшь.

Всё остальное на подобие

```
/index.php
/index.php?rand=12039
```

Кастыли обусловленые нежеланием читать документацию, бональной "нехваткой времени" что сравнимо с не желанием читать и ошибками в архитектуре приложения, или бональным "непонимаем как настроить apache или nginx" что сравнимо с "Нехваткой времени", что в свою очередь сравнимо с "нежеланием читать документацию". К сожалению это замкнутый круг, у веб девелоперов нет желания читать спецификации, легче закастылять.

Статику лучше кашировать на клиенте так как при высоких нагрузках обработка статики занимает больше процессорного времени чем обработка php. Так как apache в корне не умеет работать со статикой, используйте nginx который не замарачиваеться с определением статичный это фаил или нет и отдаёт его как вам хочеться. В нём же в две строки настраиваем и last-modified и cache-control и другие заголовки для статики, можем так же сконфигурировать чтобы last-modified был такой же как у файла на диске, т.е. залили изменения nginx отдал нужный заголовок, кэш обнавился. И не надо ничего делать...

Для разработчиков можно отключить кэш заголовком описаным выше cache-control и писать спокойно скрипты.Но скорее всего мало кто дочитал до конца, и эту строку никто не прочитал...